# React js material ui Accordion draggable resize

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, accordion, draggable

As you can see from the image I have two Accordions one on the left (30%) and one on the right (70%), when I click on the button the one on the right disappears and the one on the left becomes (100%).

[image]

What I would like to do is that there is the possibility of being able to resize the two elements that of the left and right, by means of a draggable movement.

[image]

Link: [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/vigorous-rgb-zzfc3?file=/demo.js:0-3053)

Code:

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Typography from "@material-ui/core/Typography";
import ExpandMoreIcon from "@material-ui/icons/ExpandMore";
import {
  makeStyles,
  Accordion,
  AccordionSummary,
  AccordionDetails,
  Tooltip
} from "@material-ui/core";
import { Visibility, VisibilityOff } from "@material-ui/icons";
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  root: {
    width: "100%"
  },
  heading: {
    fontSize: theme.typography.pxToRem(15),
    fontWeight: theme.typography.fontWeightRegular
  }
}));

export default function SimpleAccordion() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [showPreview, setShowPreview] = useState(true);
  const handleChangeCheck = () => {
    setShowPreview((prev) => !prev);
  };
  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <Tooltip title={showPreview ? "Show" : "Hide"} placement="bottom" arrow>
        {showPreview ? (
          <Visibility
            onClick={handleChangeCheck}
            style={{ cursor: "pointer" }}
          />
        ) : (
          <VisibilityOff
            onClick={handleChangeCheck}
            style={{ cursor: "pointer" }}
          />
        )}
      </Tooltip>
      <div
        style={{
          display: "flex"
        }}
      >
        <div
          style={{
            width: showPreview ? "30%" : "100%",
            minHeight: "500px",
            marginTop: 7,
            transition: "width 1s, height 4s"
          }}
        >
          <Accordion defaultExpanded>
            <AccordionSummary
              expandIcon={<ExpandMoreIcon />}
              aria-controls="panel1a-content"
              id="panel1a-header"
            >
              <Typography className={classes.heading}>Accordion 1</Typography>
            </AccordionSummary>
            <AccordionDetails>
              <Typography>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
                Suspendisse malesuada lacus ex, sit amet blandit leo lobortis
                eget.
              </Typography>
            </AccordionDetails>
          </Accordion>
        </div>
        {showPreview && (
          <div
            style={{
              width: "70%",
              height: "100vh",
              float: "right",
              marginTop: 7,
              marginLeft: 5
            }}
          >
            <Accordion defaultExpanded>
              <AccordionSummary
                expandIcon={<ExpandMoreIcon />}
                aria-controls="panel2a-content"
                id="panel2a-header"
              >
                <Typography className={classes.heading}>Accordion 2</Typography>
              </AccordionSummary>
              <AccordionDetails>
                <Typography>
                  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
                  Suspendisse malesuada lacus ex, sit amet blandit leo lobortis
                  eget.
                </Typography>
              </AccordionDetails>
            </Accordion>
          </div>
        )}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here i found some packages that might help you to achieve your point

[react-panelgroup](http://npmjs.com/package/react-panelgroup)

Here is a example that i made for you about mentioned package
https://codesandbox.io/s/resizable-panels-for-react-forked-0o7p4?file=/src/App.js:348-364

First

```
import PanelGroup from "react-panelgroup";
```

then use it like

```
  <PanelGroup direction="row" borderColor="grey">
          <Accordion classes={classes} />
          <Accordion classes={classes} />
          <Accordion classes={classes} />
        </PanelGroup>
```

you can costumize the min width and height of each element

```
<PanelGroup
  panelWidths={[
    { size: 100, minSize: 50, resize: 'dynamic' },
    { minSize: 100, resize: 'stretch' },
    { size: 100, minSize: 50, resize: 'dynamic' }
  ]}
>
```

also check

[react-reflex](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-reflex) document https://leefsmp.github.io/Re-Flex/index.html

Comment: It seems to work in codesandbox, but when I try it in my production code I get a weird error: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8LjXx.png

Comment: At the end of the code that you copied from sandbox remove this part `const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);`

Comment: I think that is the problem

Comment: I didn't copy that part, I just copied what's inside `ResizablePanels` and `ReturnAccordion`.

Comment: Ok that's weird :), I'm trying to figure it out

Comment: it's strange, I don't understand what happens as soon as I put those two things on, it gives me a mistake.

Comment: It seems that the problem is `ResizablePanels` if I change the definition of `ResizablePanels` to a div, it gives no problem.

Comment: Perhaps the problem is the module versions: https://codesandbox.io/s/resizable-panels-for-react-forked-egojv?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Is it working fine after you change module versions?

Comment: Looks like the problem is in the package itself, I'm working on another package if your problem is not solved with previous one.

Comment: I had to downgrade react-dom to make it work.

Comment: But I don't find much in the documentation of this module, I don't even find the original project anymore.

Do you know if there is a way to make the left or right part not go beyond a search for a resizing measure by presetting everything?

Comment: if you want to use latest features of react, it is not good to downgrade react or react dom, do you want to still do that?

Comment: Do you intend to use another library, which does the same thing?

Comment: yeah sure, i'm trying to post it

Comment: Ok thx, if it is also possible that making sure that under a certain measure does not go there, it would be great.

Comment: Was it helpful for you?

Comment: I'm reading the documentation, but from what I've seen so far react-panelgroup and react-reflex don't use percentages.

Comment: You need percentages to make on of them like 60% and another one 40%, am i right?

Comment: Yes something similar, at the beginning the two panels must have a default percentage, then the possibility to resize them should be given, but not exceeding the minimum percentage defined.

Comment: I updated the answer, please take a look at top of the answer

Comment: I had tried, in your example if you try to resize it doesn't work.